# Join scope with has_many belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Class A
 has_many :b

 def my_b_with_c
  #all B that have C and belong to A
  self.bs.has_c
 end

Class B
 belongs_to :a
 has_many :c

 scope :has_c, :join => :c

Class C
 belongs_to :b
```

My problem with this is that when i do A.first.my_b_with_c, i get duplicate records. What is the correct way to implement my_b_with_c (and/or the scope for B)
Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for all Bs that have the same C as its parent A?

Comment: actually there should not be a link between A and C, will fix the question above. I'm looking for Bs where these B have a C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it.

replaced

```
scope :has_c, :join => :c
```

with

```
scope :has_c, joins(:c).group("bs.id")
```

The next problem was doing has_c.count which needs to be has_c.all.count

Cheers